# Erlang function overloads

Tags: syntax, erlang

I've just begun fiddling with Erlang.
I've seen a lot of examples where pattern matching is used on function declarations, like so:

```
factorCount (N) ->
   Sqrt = math:sqrt (N),
   ISqrt = trunc(Sqrt),
   if ISqrt == Sqrt -> factorCount (N, ISqrt, 1, -1);
      true          -> factorCount (N, ISqrt, 1, 0)
   end.

factorCount (_N, ISqrt, Candidate, Count) when Candidate > ISqrt -> Count;
factorCount ( N, ISqrt, Candidate, Count) ->
    case N rem Candidate of
        0 -> factorCount (N, ISqrt, Candidate + 1, Count + 2);
        _ -> factorCount (N, ISqrt, Candidate + 1, Count)
    end.
```

Why is it done this way?.
e.g.

```
factorCount (_N, ISqrt, Candidate, Count) when Candidate > ISqrt -> Count;
factorCount ( N, ISqrt, Candidate, Count) ->
```

Why is that not just one function with an internal condition inside of it?

Comment: You got already good answers, I will add also that, as erlang uses recursive functions widely, it is convenient to separate the different cases  of recursion in different clauses: like this you have the test case in first line, and  the recursive call (or returned value for base cases) on the last line of each clause, with some comment per clause it is really easier to read and maintain.

Answer (score 5):

One reason is for readability and maintainability. Conditions inside functions tend to make the code creep to the right due to additional indentation, and that combined with the extra conditions in the body make for longer functions that are harder to read, reason about, and maintain.

Another reason is that functions often have preconditions, and guards can often help express those preconditions more clearly than code embedded within the function body.

Still aother reason is that pattern matching the arguments always occurs when functions are called, since that's essentially how function arguments get their bindings, so it's natural to then make use of those bound values in guards. Guards are a kind of extension to pattern matching, allowing you to check things that pattern matching alone can't check.

Answer (score 3):

Besides [Steve's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/409228/steve-vinoski) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33104850/49197), it will be more obvious if I rewrite your code:

```
factorCount(_N, ISqrt, Candidate, Count)
  when Candidate > ISqrt ->
    Count;
factorCount(N, ISqrt, Candidate, Count)
  when N rem Candidate =:= 0 ->
    factorCount(N, ISqrt, Candidate + 1, Count + 2);
factorCount(N, ISqrt, Candidate, Count) ->
    factorCount(N, ISqrt, Candidate + 1, Count).
```

It become more obvious in code where you combine pattern matching with some guards:

```
merge([{K, V1} | T1], [{K, V2} | T2]) ->
    [{K, [V1, V2]} | merge(T1, T2)];
merge([{K1, V1} | T1], [{K2, _} | _] = L2)
  when K1 < K2 ->
    [{K1, [V1]} | merge(T1, L2)];
merge(L1, [{K2, V2} | T2]) ->
    [{K2, [V2]} | merge(L1, T2)];
merge(L1, []) ->
    [{K, [V]} || {K, V} <- L1].
```

It would not make much sense if I combine the second and the third function clauses together just to make `K1 < K2` comparison inside of the function clause.

Comment: But honestly [this](https://gist.github.com/Lol4t0/8410e791343730efb89f) look better for me

Comment: I think that Hynek's indentation looks ugly and Lol4t0's indentation looks nice, but that use of `if`s and the redundant test at the end makes it look like you just came from a procedural language.

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot that not redundant test but explicit test. Explicit is always preferable to implicit.

Comment: @Lol4t0: You are right that explicit test is preferable, but there is not such test in original code which could be intentional. There is also missing explicit `Candidate =< ISqrt` in your `if` cases which you should also consider if you want to be explicit. So [this](https://gist.github.com/pichi/4a0099f60a71c2d4eb2b) version seems more idiomatic. Anyway using function clauses is a more common way because of wide using of pattern matching. You don't want use different style with and without pattern matching.

Comment: @Hynek, first of all _original_ code had explicit test. It is your code where it got lost. Then in this _particular_ case a lot of overloads generate a lot of _repetitio n_, that is bad.

Comment: @Lol4t0: No, I don't see `N rem Candidate =/= 0` anywhere in the original code. And in this particular case there are not any overloads at all so I don't know what you are talking about. BTW how much Erlang code you wrote so far, because it is all about how Erlang code is usually written in practice and there seems to be difference in experience between you and me as big as between me and Steve Vinosky and it is pretty big.

Comment: Look more attentively: it is in case: obviously `N rem Candidate` can be either 0 or not 0. And it is checked with a separate case. BTW I've seen more ugly Erlang code than I wish.